# Order the default option in select in the first by angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I've been working with angular. I am using data from json and push it to array object and display in the options in select element.

My concern is: After default option with selection and after that only options fron json data s is displayed.

Finally, here's the snippet of HTML which gets generated:

```
<select id="filterAssignedWorkgroupName_select" class="form-control ng-valid ng-scope selectPlaceholder ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid-parse" ng-class="{'selectPlaceholder':options.placeholder}" ng-model="result[options.key]" ng-options="option.value as option.name for option in selectOptions" name="filterAssignedWorkgroupName" result="result" options="options" ng-change="onChangeFunction()">
  <!-- ngIf: options.placeholder -->
  <option value="0" label="BrodieBuild12_10">BrodieBuild12_10</option>
  <option value="1" label="Liberty ITyyy">Liberty ITyyy</option>
  <option value="2" label="Jon Break - Group">Jon Break - Group</option>
  <option value="3" label="Jon Break Dash - Group">Jon Break Dash - Group
  </option>
  <option value="4" label="Internet Team Tasks">Internet Team Tasks</option>
  <option value="5" label="Jon Test Group 12-2">Jon Test Group 12-2</option>
  <option ng-if="options.placeholder" value="" selected="" class="ng-binding ng-scope">Select Workgroups</option>
  <!-- end ngIf:
options.placeholder -->
</select>
```

What do I need to do to get rid of it?

the below be in the first option and selected. When am running this would be the top of the option but it display in last option.

```
  <option ng-if="options.placeholder" value="" selected=""
    class="ng-binding ng-scope">Select Workgroups</option><!-- end ngIf:
    options.placeholder --></select>
```

Comment: Are you trying to remove `<option>Select Workgroups</option>` from the `<select>` once another item is selected?

Comment: @New Dev the problem is when I drop down the select option it is listed in the last option field with selected. I need it is displayed in the first option with selected

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

Given the following `$scope.items`:

```
$scope.items = [
    {id: 1, val: "foo"},
    {id: 2, val: "bar"},
    {id: 3, val: "baz"},
    // ...
    ];
```

The following View will show "Select item" first, and once an item is sekect, it will then remove it from the list of options:

```
<select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item as item.val for item in items">
  <option ng-if="!selectedItem" value="">Select item</option>
</select>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SefGO4BcfR3hrmwxtylv?p=preview)

Comment: No. The thing is am using array push dynamically in javascript. so what happen means, when i click drop down from the select the default option is displayed in the last option after the loading of all the datas from array. So i need to be display in the first option as default option usually using javascript.                 usually it displayed as: one two three four --select-- But i need to diplay as --select--  one two three

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand. Here's a [modified plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZBmsiDHARqd3ZIhPmtPQ?p=preview) where I add more items dynamically. "--select--" still appears first.

Comment: yes dev its working. But the thing is am using the meta driven field directive and also using placeholder am using. <option ng-if="options.placeholder" value="" selected=""
    class="ng-binding ng-scope">{{ options.placeholder }}</option><!-- end ngIf:
    options.placeholder --></select>

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. What is "meta driven field directive". What is `options.placeholder`?